# entity framework insert not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I learned some basic stuff on EF 4.0 and recently upgraded to EF 6.0. I can't seem to get a simple insert working. Has the "ent.AddtoImage()" been deprecated in version 6.0? I searched around but cannot find an answer.

```
using (evEntities ent = new evEntities())
{
Image insertImg = new Image();                                        

insertImg.TypeID = "a";
ent.AddtoImage(insertImg);
ent.SaveChanges();
}
```

I get a red squiggly line under AddtoImage   ???

Edit: here is an image -

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that Image is an entity generated by EF you can use

```
ent.Images.Add(insertImg);
```

in EF6, then the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah.

beacause evEntities is valid only in the scope of the using statement, which is the next block.

As you miss {} - that next blcock is the next statement, which is

```
Image insertImg = new Image ();
```

Right after that line, evEntities is disposed and the variable invalid.

Wrap the whole lines after using into curly braces to make them one block.

```
using (evEntities ent = new evEntities()) {
    ....rest of your code
}
```

Comment: sorry, I left out the braces. I actually have a lot of other code and was trying to simplify. But yeah, I have the braces/scope in my code. So AddToImage(insertImg) should work?

Comment: No idea, my crystal ball is broken. I have no idea about where this method comes from as you clearly do not love giving any relevant code. I find no reference to an AddTOImage method even in EF 4.... or on the whole internet.

Comment: Late and tired. Yes, you're right that I should have posted better. Thank you ... It's a usage of "Addto" which doesn't seem to be supported with EF 6. Here's the ref: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2008/08/21/ado-net-entity-insert-update-and-delete.aspx  --- the Insert example uses AddtoEmp

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
evEntities.Entry<Image>(ent).State = EntityState.Added;
ent.SaveChanges();
```

or

```
evEntities.Set<Image>().Add(ent);
ent.SaveChanges();
```